# What's the correct way to access a field in an array element with php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm getting a few rows from the DB with an ajax call in PHP and I save the result to an array with javascript.
Then I make some changes in the data and wish to update the DB.
So I use another ajax call for that but I can't manage to access the fields inside the rows correctly.
When I try this I get nothing:

```
echo $bArray[$i].branchId;
```

When I try this:

```
echo json_encode($bArray[$i].branchId);
```

I get `ArraybranchId` instead of the field value.

What's the correct way to access the field with php?

Comment: The correct way to address array elements in PHP is `arrayname[index]`, but what form are you sending the data in in the first place?

Comment: What is `$bArray`? What is `$bArray[$i]`? In PHP you either have to use `obj->member` when you deal with objects or `array[index]` with arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. `$bArray` is the array, `$i` is the index to show which element in the array we're addressing. Sorry for not being clear enough. Will improve that. Pekka, I didn't understand the question about the form. I'm using an ajax call from javascript and the code I wrote above is from the php file which contains the ajax itself. Anyway, I got my answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either for array:

```
$bArray[$i]['branchId']
```

or for object:

```
$bArray[$i]->branchId
```

depending which type `$bArray[$i]` is (array or object). You have not written in your question, so I showed both ways.

Answer (score 2):

I take it `branchId` is the name of the field, and you want the `value` for that field?

If so, it's:

`echo $bArray['branchId'];` or
`echo $bArray[$i]['branchId']`

**Edit**: Also, you'll need to make sure you're using `mysql_fetch_assoc` not `mysql_fetch_array`!

Comment: thanks. `echo $bArray[$i]['branchId']` was the right way to go. +1.